# Xamarin native windows app development on visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, xamarin.uwp, xamarin.winphone

I have installed visual studio 2017 in my windows machine and I have installed `Xamarin` along with that, but when I am creating `Xamarin` native in visual studio I am getting `project.iOS` and `project.Android` but there is nothing for windows. If `project.winphone` is not available I was hoping `project.uwp` will be available.

A screenshot of the solution explorer is here:

[image]

Am I missing any windows SDK? Do I have to install separately?

If anybody explain with some details it'd be very good for people who are starting up in `Xamarin` windows app development.

Update:

[Screenshot of Extensions and Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4trjE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce your issue in my visual studio 2017. It seems that there is some issue with Xamarin.Forms templates extension.
[image]

You could solve the issue by updating your visual studio 2017 to the latest version.

Click Tools button -> Extensins And Updates-> Updates-> Product Updates.

[image]

Comment: Please try to reinstall Xamarin Mobile component if there is no Visual Studio Update package in the update list.